# Risk free rate for Performance Analytics

Tags: r, performanceanalytics

In [R] one can pass either a vector or scalar as the risk free rate.  What is better?  If I pass a vector to (for example) chart.riskreturnscatter then the sharpe ratio lines disappear.

```
chart.RiskReturnScatter(managers[,c(1,2,3)],0.01)
chart.RiskReturnScatter(managers[,c(1,2,3)],managers[,10])
```

So is this a feature?

Thanks,
Raghu

Answer (score 1):

This is a feature, when you pass a vector it's because the risk free rate has changed over time. E.g. you can assume a constant or changing risk free rate as each period of returns can have an associated risk free rate.

Comment: Kyle - Thanks for the response.  I appreciate why one would want a varying Rf but if I pass a vector I can't get the Sharpe lines on the graph.  Do Sharpe line not make sense with a varying Rf rate?

Comment: Try playing the graphical parameters to ensure your lines are not out of range of the graph.

Comment: In chart.RiskReturnScatter,  Sharpe lines are added using
    abline(a = (Rf * 12), b = add.sharpe[line], col = "gray", 
             lty = 2)
    }
(where b = c(1,2,3))  This won't work if Rf is a vector because a has to be a scalar.

Comment: # @todo: Drawing Sharpe ratio lines currently throws warnings; change test statement, from the source code, likely it's a work in progress.